# Nginx-extras installation on debian 8

Tags: linux, nginx, debian

I have a problem with intallation of nginx-extras on a debian 8 server 8.11. The 'apt-get install nginx-extras' return me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-extras : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.6.2-5+deb8u6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The installed nginx version is: 1.15.12
Below the apt sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx
```

Any idea how solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. I hope the answer provided by another user is helpful. If you find the answer helpful, please don't forget to upvote on it. Ref: https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers .

Answer (score 1):

There is no such package named `nginx-extras` in the official nginx apt repository, which you have chosen to use. That name is a Debian name only, and refers to Debian's custom build of nginx with a variety of third party modules included.

The official nginx repo contains only `nginx`, which contains most nginx modules, and some separate module packages `nginx-module-geoip`, `nginx-module-image-filter`, `nginx-module-njs`, `nginx-module-perl`, `nginx-module-xslt` and `nginx-nr-agent`. It does not contain third party modules at all.

How you "solve" the problem depends on what version of nginx you need to run and what specific modules you need to use.

Comment: ah ok, so, the ngx_http_headers_module that was in the nginx-extras, now is included in my version of nginx (1.15.12)?

Comment: @StefanoGuarella AFAIK that module is always included in nginx.